# Find length of common arc of two circles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Given centre and radius of two circles which intersects. We need to find arc length common to both circles.

My approach is to find the 2 intersecting points of two circles and then find arc length represented by them. This can be done neatly as given [here](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/circles_intersection) but problem with this approach is that by two points on a circle we could be representing 2 arcs - major or minor. To solve this problem we need to find 2 intersecting points as an ordered pair of points, which I cannot find how to do. Reducing problem to Circle-Line intersection as given in link produces unordered pair of points.

Probably we can find formula to directly find arclength directly but I am not interested in it, as I find my approach more general/useful for solving computational geometry problems.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqVqa.png): [image]

Comment: What is `arc length common to both circles.` ? Could you show a picture to make things clearer?

Comment: Would like to help you but my Russian is not good so I have trouble understanding the "here" example

Comment: @MBo : Added image.. here arc to both circles is defined by common points B,D. I'll correct i think 'common arc length' is a lot misleading. I meant that if we take clockwise.. then correct order of B,D is B,D and not D,B.

Comment: @Aldert Thanks! No need to read the link, just assume circle-circle intersection can be found out, only problem is its not ordered as i described in comment i described above.

Comment: B-D is common chord. Arcs are DCB and BAD - but it is hard to call them common. Are circle radii always equal?

Comment: @MBo yes that was my bad in description as you pointed out. by common i meant the two points which are common. So now BD clockwise would represent one arc of circle, anticlockwise would represent different arc of same circle. I'll update this in description of question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You can address this by trigonometry, solving the triangle formed by the centers and the intersection. The angles give you the arcs.

[image]